# Unity Player Rotation Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation

I am creating a game using Unity where the player has to use the wasd to move the player 1 tile at a time (3D), I would like to make the player rotate smoothly with movement accordingly when one of the keys is pressed as seen in the image below. I have tried countless approaches but still can't seem to make it work would appreciate it if you can help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lerping is good for moving smoothly from one position to another you can refactor code from here and call

```
void update() {
if (Input.GetKey("w")) {
//begin lerp up
}
//program same for asd 
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: This is a good answer, just thought it might be helpful to add that unity stores rotation as a quaternion *(even in 2D games)* and there is a dedicated `Lerp` function for lerping quaternions [Quaternion.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) which might work better than `Lerp`